# Nginx Ingress controllers

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

We have a services which can be accessed through both http and https protocol. Since we have some authorization module based on the both http and https protocol we need to redirect the http request to port number 80 and https based request to 443 port number respectively.

For Example:

Would it also be possible to allow listening to multiple ports (e.g. 443 and 80) and then forward incoming requests to https://demo.example.com to service1 and http://demo.example.com to service2?

We have configured the Nginx Ingress controllers as below:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: lenspiingress
  namespace: nginx-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
    ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - demo.example.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: demo.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: apidemo
          servicePort: 80
```

And our services is like,

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: demodeployment
  name: apidemo
  namespace: nginx-ingress
spec:
  ports:
  - name: port-1
    nodePort: 31120
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: port-2
    nodePort: 30850
    port: 443   
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    run: demodeployment
  type: NodePort
```

While using Nginx ingress controller we can redirect to any one of the port either 80 or 443.

Is this possible to setup the ingress to redirect http request to port 80 and https based request to port 443?We are meaning is there any parameters we can set the listen port in "Ingress" and redirect based on the ports.

Here is my nginx.conf:

```
daemon off;

worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

worker_rlimit_nofile 261120;
events {
    multi_accept        on;
    worker_connections  16384;
    use                 epoll;
}

http {
    real_ip_header      X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from    0.0.0.0/0;

    real_ip_recursive   on;

    geoip_country       /etc/nginx/GeoIP.dat;
    geoip_city          /etc/nginx/GeoLiteCity.dat;
    geoip_proxy_recursive on;

    vhost_traffic_status_zone shared:vhost_traffic_status:10m;
    vhost_traffic_status_filter_by_set_key $geoip_country_code country::*;

    # lua section to return proper error codes when custom pages are used
    lua_package_path '.?.lua;./etc/nginx/lua/?.lua;/etc/nginx/lua/vendor/lua-resty-http/lib/?.lua;';
    init_by_lua_block {
        require("error_page")
    }

    sendfile            on;
    aio                 threads;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;

    log_subrequest      on;

    reset_timedout_connection on;

    keepalive_timeout 75s;

    client_header_buffer_size       1k;
    large_client_header_buffers     4 8k;
    http2_max_field_size            4k;
    http2_max_header_size           16k;

    types_hash_max_size             2048;
    server_names_hash_max_size      512;
    server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;
    map_hash_bucket_size            64;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type text/html;
    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level 5;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_min_length 256;
    gzip_types application/atom+xml application/javascript application/x-javascript application/json application/rss+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf application/x-web-app-manifest+json application/xhtml+xml application/xml font/opentype image/svg+xml image/x-icon text/css text/plain text/x-component;
    gzip_proxied any;

    server_tokens on;

    log_format upstreaminfo '$remote_addr - [$proxy_add_x_forwarded_for] - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $request_length $request_time [$proxy_upstream_name] $upstream_addr $upstream_response_length $upstream_response_time $upstream_status"';

    map $request_uri $loggable {
        default 1;
    }

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstreaminfo if=$loggable;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;

    resolver 10.0.4.124 valid=30s;

    # Retain the default nginx handling of requests without a "Connection" header
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default          upgrade;
        ''               close;
    }

    # trust http_x_forwarded_proto headers correctly indicate ssl offloading
    map $http_x_forwarded_proto $pass_access_scheme {
        default          $http_x_forwarded_proto;
        ''               $scheme;
    }

    map $http_x_forwarded_port $pass_server_port {
       default           $http_x_forwarded_port;
       ''                $server_port;
    }

    # map port 442 to 443 for header X-Forwarded-Port
    map $pass_server_port $pass_port {
        442              443;
        default          $pass_server_port;
    }

    # Map a response error watching the header Content-Type
    map $http_accept $httpAccept {
        default          html;
        application/json json;
        application/xml  xml;
        text/plain       text;
    }

    map $httpAccept $httpReturnType {
        default          text/html;
        json             application/json;
        xml              application/xml;
        text             text/plain;
    }

    server_name_in_redirect off;
    port_in_redirect        off;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    # turn on session caching to drastically improve performance
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;

    # allow configuring ssl session tickets
    ssl_session_tickets on;

    # slightly reduce the time-to-first-byte
    ssl_buffer_size 4k;

    # allow configuring custom ssl ciphers
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
    proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout invalid_header http_502 http_503 http_504;

    upstream nginx-ingress-apidemo-80 {
        sticky hash=sha1 name=route  httponly;
        server 10.244.1.32:80 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;
        server 10.244.5.48:80 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;
        server 10.244.5.49:80 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;
    }
    upstream upstream-default-backend {
        least_conn;
        server 10.244.5.41:8080 max_fails=0 fail_timeout=0;
    }
    server {
        server_name _;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=off reuseport backlog=511;
        listen [::]:443   default_server ipv6only=off reuseport backlog=511 ssl http2;
        # PEM sha: 5ea101804f658b288ff4aa2d3f2641d348027fed
        ssl_certificate                         /ingress-controller/ssl/nginx-ingress-tls-secret.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key                     /ingress-controller/ssl/nginx-ingress-tls-secret.pem;

        more_set_headers                        "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains; preload";

        vhost_traffic_status_filter_by_set_key $geoip_country_code country::$server_name;
        location / {
            set $proxy_upstream_name "upstream-default-backend";
            port_in_redirect off;
            client_max_body_size                    "1m";

            proxy_set_header Host                   $host;

            # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

            # Pass Real IP
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

            # Allow websocket connections
            proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI         $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

            # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
            # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
            proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

            # Custom headers

            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

            proxy_redirect                          off;
            proxy_buffering                         off;
            proxy_buffer_size                       "4k";
            proxy_buffers                           4 "4k";

            proxy_http_version                      1.1;

            proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
            proxy_cookie_path                       off;

            proxy_pass http://upstream-default-backend;
        }

        # health checks in cloud providers require the use of port 80
        location /healthz {
            access_log off;
            return 200;
        }

        # this is required to avoid error if nginx is being monitored
        # with an external software (like sysdig)
        location /nginx_status {
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;

            access_log off;
            stub_status on;
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name demo.example.com;
        listen [::]:80;
        vhost_traffic_status_filter_by_set_key $geoip_country_code country::$server_name;
        location / {
            set $proxy_upstream_name "nginx-ingress-apidemo-80";
            port_in_redirect off;
            client_max_body_size                    "1m";

            proxy_set_header Host                   $host;

            # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

            # Pass Real IP
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

            # Allow websocket connections
            proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Original-URI         $request_uri;
            proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

            # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
            # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
            proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

            # Custom headers

            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      60s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      60s;

            proxy_redirect                          off;
            proxy_buffering                         off;
            proxy_buffer_size                       "4k";
            proxy_buffers                           4 "4k";

            proxy_http_version                      1.1;

            proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
            proxy_cookie_path                       off;

            proxy_pass http://nginx-ingress-apidemo-80;
        }

    }
    # default server, used for NGINX healthcheck and access to nginx stats
    server {
        # Use the port 18080 (random value just to avoid known ports) as default port for nginx.
        # Changing this value requires a change in:
        # https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/blob/master/ingress/controllers/nginx/nginx/command.go#L104
        listen [::]:18080 ipv6only=off default_server reuseport backlog=511;

        location /healthz {
            access_log off;
            return 200;
        }

        location /nginx_status {
            set $proxy_upstream_name "internal";

            vhost_traffic_status_display;
            vhost_traffic_status_display_format html;
        }

        # this location is used to extract nginx metrics
        # using prometheus.
        # TODO: enable extraction for vts module.
        location /internal_nginx_status {
            set $proxy_upstream_name "internal";

            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow ::1;
            deny all;

            access_log off;
            stub_status on;
        }

        location / {
            set $proxy_upstream_name "upstream-default-backend";
            proxy_pass             http://upstream-default-backend;
        }

    }

    # default server for services without endpoints
    server {
        listen 8181;
        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        location / {
            return 503;
        }
    }
}

stream {

    # TCP services

    # UDP services
}
```

Comment: if client access our services "https://demo.example.com" it should be redirected to 443 of service and if the client "https://demo.example.com" it should be redirected to 80 of service. Aren't both the urls same? also post your nginx config

Comment: @Tarun Lalwani, Yes the URL are same. The difference is that when client client access https://demo.example.com:443 it should redirected to 443 of services and if they access http://demo.example.com:80 it should  redirected to 80 of services.

Comment: That would only happen when they change https to http for 80 port. You cant have https on both. Also post your nginx config

Comment: Thanks for pointing out , there seems to be a typo . I have changed it in the question and also added the nginx.conf

Comment: Would it also be possible to allow listening to multiple ports (e.g.8443 and 8080) and then forward incoming requests to https://demo.example.com:8443 to service1 and http://demo.example.com:8080 to service2 in kubernetes ingress controllers?

Comment: You can listen to as many ports as you like

Comment: as far as I can see the current Ingress implementation doesn't support your usecase. It's not possible to redirect traffic for the same domain to different services based on the used port. I recommend to just redirect all traffic to https by adding this Ingress annotation: "ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect": "true".